# Running a Java Eclipse Project from Command line

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

Hi I wanted to run a java Eclipse project form command line.. I tried making a Jar and Runnable Jar (Both options), with the manifest when needed.

The problem which I cannot solve is that it always ends up giving me a FileNotFound error when My program tried to read a txt file. How do I solve this error? I cannot find it online.

Thanks

Example:

`in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CompanyNameListModified.txt"));`

Error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: CompanyNameListModified.txt (No such file or directory)`

Comment: is that file in the same directory as your java program? If not you need to put the full path to that file in the code

Comment: I did that. I tried putting the path in the form of Project/filename, since it won't read the path from my Harddisk like User/name/workspace..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the text file is in the jar itself, then don't grab it as a File, since technically, these don't exist in jar files, but rather get it as a resource.

e.g.,

```
package foo;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestResource {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();     
      String resourceName = "foo/movies.txt"; // path relative to classloader
      InputStream inStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inStream);
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
      }
      if (scanner != null) {
         scanner.close();
      }
   }   
}
```

the contents of the jar file are:

```
C:\Users\hovercraft\Jar files>jar tf TestResource.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
foo/TestResource.class
foo/TestResource.java
foo/movies.txt
```

Comment: Ok is this how I do it? `The Class class has a getResourceAsStream method and you can use this to get your resource from the Jar, then use an InputStreamReader then a BufferedReader.'

Comment: @sa_nyc: exactly. do that.

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception. I think it has to do smthn with file path. What is the right way for that?

Comment: @sa_nyc: Example program changed. Please note that structure of my test Jar file. Please do print out the structure of yours via jar's `tf`  command.

Comment: as in java -tf jarname.jar ??

Comment: No, as i show. This is used when running jar.exe not java.exe.